# Facebook Black Screen when in IFrame

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have Facebook in an Iframe for the convenience of my clients.
But all of a sudden it doesn't work..  It simply covers itself with a black screen.
Is there a work around? 
Something I can do.  Maybe even have someone code to their API to get all the functionality back.
Is there a sollution already out there??

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/" width=800 height=600 /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like they are doing this on purpose to stop xss or similar attacks.

Comment: Yea i understand that they don't want click jackign etc... But do you know of anyone who has a web app that will do the same thing maybe through Facebook API that i can embed?

Comment: I cant think how this could possible be convenient to your clients

Comment: thats not the exact code
but in my application i have a simple tab called facebook.  While they are jamming around sending people emails they can log in and talk to one of their clients on facebook if they want to or need to and still stay within our application.  it is very convenient.

Comment: Perhaps by using a facebook api instead of embedding the whole app in the page?

Comment: Thats fine... Now im wondering 
1) is it out there?
2) who do i pay to do it quickly?

Comment: try http://www.rentacoder.com and read this great guide http://blog.cubeofm.com/the-subtleties-in-outsourcing-using-rentacode